How to iterate through an array made of pointer that is returned from a function?
I have a function called int *abc() which returns a pointer array and I called it int *num = abc();
Everything is fine until I want to loop through the array, which the sizeof(num) returns 8, so is the strlen(num) a good choice? or is there any better option?.
int *abc() {
    return [1,2,3,4];
}

int main() {
    int *num = abc();

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(num); i++) {
        printf("blah blah blah");
    }

    return 0;
}

my question is how am I supposed to loop through it?
Doesn't c have any kind of foreach loop?

You'll have to provide the size separately - there's no way to discover it from the pointer alone - at least no documented, portable way.

Declaring a function as int* abc() says it returns a pointer to int, not an array of pointers. Edit your post to show a [mre].

@500-InternalServerError There isn't even a non-portable way in most implementations.


Everything is fine until I want to loop through the array, which the sizeof(num) returns 8 all the time.

In your code, num is a pointer. Its size never changes.
You cannot derive the number of elements from the pointer. You need to provide the number via another variable.
Either by adding a parameter like size_t *number_of_results that is set to the correct number before the function returns.
Or by adding a sentinel value to the array.
E.g. if you do not allow negative values in your array, you could mark the last entry with -1. Or 0 as it is done for strings in C.
